# HTML5 offline caching database storage

Tags: javascript, json, html, offline-caching, offline-browsing

Im working on an HTML5 offline app im using a json string as my database

```
 [
            {"id":"1","data":"a","group_name":"erwr"},
            {"id":"2","data":"b","group_name":"dasd"},                        
            {"id":"3","data":"c","group_name":"yjg"},         
             -------------------------------
             -------------------------------
                 // it has around 3000 elements
    ]
```

Is it a good idea to store this entire json in a variable and assign like

```
var mydatabase = "the above json";
localStorage.setItem('mydb', JSON.stringify(mydatabase ));
```

I think there are some limitations with the maximum number of characters for a var in javascript.so that the possibility of missing some elements in the json.

Another alternative that im using is put the entire thing in a hidden div

```
<div id="db" style="display:none">/**the above json**/</div>
```

and accessing like

```
var mydb = $('#db').html();
localStorage.setItem('mydb',mydb);
```

My question is that the second method an optimal one ? if not someone please provide another optimal way.

Comment: Is it a static DB? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `localStoage` method is fine. Most browsers support at least 5 MB for `localStorage` and your data rows look small. There is no fixed limit on Javascript variable size.

Putting it in a hidden `<div>` will slow down initial page load.